# How to Query Contact History in Android

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm using a Motorola Backflip running Android 2.1.  Every contact in my phone has a History tab which shows recent history such as recent texts, calls, and facebook messages for that person (facebook is linked through motoblur).  My questions are:
1) Is the history tab on every Android Device or is it only from Motoblur?
2) If it is an Android entity, is it possible to query this information using the new ContactsContract and SQLite calls, if so, how?
If it's only a motoblur entity, how does motoblur query that information to provide? (ie. how would you pull all contact history from calls, texts, and facebook because a linear search would be far inefficient.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's definitely a device-specific thing. You'll have to see if motorola has an api for getting that information, which it almost certainly doesn't. It's just a custom app.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to post any API information here if I find it.